# gdal2tiles rx, ry, rxsize, rysize, wx, wy, wxsize, wysize

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

Reading the source code of gdal2tiles.py, one often comes across the variables `rx, ry, rxsize, rysize, wx, wy, wxsize and wysize`.

For example, when reading raster data, you encounter:

`data = ds.ReadRaster(rx, ry, rxsize, rysize, wxsize, wysize, band_list=list(range(1, dataBandsCount + 1)))`

How does `rx, ry, rxsize, rysize, wxsize and wysize` relate to the actual raster file being read? It's not immediately obvious from reading the documentation.

Further down from there, `gdal2tiles.py` does:

```
# TODO: fill the null value in case a tile without alpha is produced (now
# only png tiles are supported)
dsquery.WriteRaster(wx, wy, wxsize, wysize, data, band_list=list(range(1, dataBandsCount + 1)))
dsquery.WriteRaster(wx, wy, wxsize, wysize, alpha, band_list=[tilebands])

scale_query_to_tile(dsquery, dstile, tile_job_info.tile_driver, options, tilefilename=tilefilename)

Basically the question is, what are the `r` variables and the `w` variables in relation to the source raster?
```

Comment: I guess that "r" means raster, the whole input dataset. And "w" could stand for window, a subset of source data that is finally written into a tile as scaled.

Comment: The docs call those parameters `xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize, buf_xsize, buf_ysize`.  The first four relate to the source raster, and any `buf` param relates to the buffer that the data gets read into.  If omitted/left to none, [they default to `xsize` and `ysize`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-pysrc.html#Dataset.ReadRaster).  If you're not specifying an existing `buf_obj` to read into there's probably no reason to touch any of those, as far as I understand

Comment: The docs for the c++ API have better descriptions than the Python ones.  See:  https://gdal.org/api/gdaldataset_cpp.html#_CPPv4N11GDALDataset8RasterIOE10GDALRWFlagiiiiPvii12GDALDataTypeiPi8GSpacing8GSpacing8GSpacingP20GDALRasterIOExtraArg